# JQUERY - Ajax.Load - Multiple Scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, scripting, load

well i have a problem, im using Ajax with Jquery, using the Jquery.Load() function.
Happens that i want to have a "countdown" javascript on a certain page.
The problem is, when i call that page with ajax, it does all normally, but if i click the link again, the countdown doubles speed, if i do again it keeps going faster and faster. There is some script to flush the old script and start again? or to not load again the script?
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something is calling either `setInterval` or `setTimeout` every time you `$.load`.  That code would need to be modified so that it the countdown is only started once.  Since you haven't pasted your code, all I can suggest is something that looks like this...

```
if (!window.timerId) {
    window.timerId = setInterval(callback, interval);
}

// later, when the countdown is over:
window.timerId = null;
```